# Error in image extraction with iText 5: "The color space is not supported"

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to write a program to extract all the embedded images from a PDF file. Unfortunately, many input files result in similar exceptions:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.UnsupportedPdfException: The color space [blah blah blah] is not supported.
```

The file that generated the traceback is password protected and I cannot unprotect it nor share the password, I'm afraid. However, I've encountered the error with more than one file from multiple sources. These files are perfectly viewable and printable in both OS X Preview and Acrobat Reader, so I'm pretty sure the problem is with iText and not the files.

I'm using iText 5.5.6 and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31 on OS X 10.10.3 but the same error has been occurring over several iText, JDK and OS versions; I've just now gotten around to asking about it.

The code (main loop just calls `PdfReaderContentParser.processContent` with an instance of this class):

```
package info.metalfatigue;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;

public class MyImageRenderListener implements RenderListener {
    private final String path;

    public MyImageRenderListener(final String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(
            @SuppressWarnings("unused") final TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(final ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        try {
            final PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
            final PdfName filter = (PdfName)image.get(PdfName.FILTER);
            if (PdfName.DCTDECODE.equals(filter)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
                final String filename =
                        String.format(
                                path,
                                renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(),
                                "jpg");
                final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
                os.close();
            } else if (PdfName.JPXDECODE.equals(filter)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
                final String filename =
                        String.format(
                                path,
                                renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(),
                                "jp2");
                final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
                os.close();
            } else {
                final BufferedImage awtImage = image.getBufferedImage();
                if (null != awtImage) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
                    final String filename =
                            String.format(
                                    path,
                                    renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(),
                                    "png");
                    final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                    ImageIO.write(awtImage, "png", os);
                    os.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

An example exception traceback:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.UnsupportedPdfException: The color space [/DeviceN, [/Black], /DeviceCMYK, 1153 0 R, 1152 0 R] is not supported.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.decodeImageBytes(PdfImageObject.java:323)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.<init>(PdfImageObject.java:200)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.<init>(PdfImageObject.java:169)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo.prepareImageObject(ImageRenderInfo.java:124)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo.getImage(ImageRenderInfo.java:114)
    at info.metalfatigue.MyImageRenderListener.renderImage(MyImageRenderListener.java:42)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$ImageXObjectDoHandler.handleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:1268)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.displayXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:352)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.access$6100(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:60)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$Do.invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:988)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:286)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:429)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:80)
    at info.metalfatigue.PdfImgEx.main(PdfImgEx.java:23)
```

Comment: Considering *[blah blah blah]* actually is *[/DeviceN, [/Black], /DeviceCMYK, 1153 0 R, 1152 0 R]*, i assume the colour space indeed is not supported by iText for image rendering.

Comment: Indeed. The error message is clear, isn't it? What's the problem? If metalfatigue is a customer, a ticket can be created in our issue tracker. If metalfatigue is not a customer, metalfatigue can implement the unsupported functionality and contribute the code back to the community.

Comment: @MetalFatigue I'd propose surrounding your `renderInfo.getImage()` by an appropriate `try-catch` to handle such cases of images with interesting color spaces.

Comment: @mkl Not the only such unimplemented color space I've seen, thus the ellipsis.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Would be nice to have known what parts of the PDF spec iText isn't trying to cover.

Comment: It's not iText alone: the actual creation of images (such as PNG) is done by the Java SDK. If it's not supported by the Java SDK, it's not supported in iText (unless we write custom image creation functionality).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you! That's much more helpful.